# C# file info in datagridview

Tags: c#, file, gridview, directory

I can't to count number of files within a directory using **DirectoryInfo** and **FileInfo**

I have tried this code without success, because I don't have error but can't show in gridview.

My code below.

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

```
public DataTable getAllFiles()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM doTable ;");

    using (OdbcConnection cn =
      new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (OdbcCommand cmd =
            new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();

                using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add("Nr of Files in directory");

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            FilePath = Server.MapPath("/aspnet/" + reader["sFolder"].ToString().Replace('/', '\\'));

                            Response.Write(FilePath);

                            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@FilePath);
                            DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = directory.GetDirectories();
                            FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();

                            foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirectories)
                            {
                                int nrFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirInfo.FullName, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
                                Response.Write(nrFiles.ToString() + "<br />");
                                //Here the output is correct//

                                foreach (FileInfo f in files)
                                {
                                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                                    dr[0] = nrFiles.ToString();
                                }

                                gvDownload.DataSource = subDirectories;
                                gvDownload.DataBind();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

**#Edit 01**

[image]

I need show the **nr files on subdirectory** on **GridView Control**, now is empty :

[image]

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do ?

Comment: @alexay68 thank you for reply. I try to show in gridview folder, subfolder and file within a directory on my server. In DB I have memorized on column sFolder this string control/Imp/foo

Answer (score 0):

`files`contains the files of `directory` - `nrFiles` are the amount of files of the subdirectories of `directory` - you probably want the to requery the files from the subdirectory your currently in instead of reusing the `files` from it´s parent folder

Comment: thank you for reply, please see **#Edit 01** in my first question-

Comment: 1. You are - in the foreach over the subdirectories-  rebinding subdirectories over and over - move it out of the loop.
2. you fill a local DataTable dt, that has no Connection to the datasource you are binding.
3. you might need some valueconverter that converts your bound subdirectories to something that is displayable - not enough Code to know exactly whats needed - and this is another question and Problem alltogether.

Comment: Thanks, I can also change system and code to achieve the goal. Do you have suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

About you want to show folder and all files of this folder in gridview, please check this article:

[Nested GridView Example in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)